# how to get collaborators with project id in Laravel 5.2 in the localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing project management application using Laravel 5.2. in My application side bar menus as sidebar.blade.php witch located in views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php

```
<li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('projects.index') }}">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('collaborators.form')}}">Collaborators</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Todos</a></li>
```

when I click project link in the sidebar pages view existing pages. and now I need add some collaborators to each project when click collaborators link in the sidebar. my collaborators form in view/collaborators/form

```
 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:15px;padding:10px;">
                <h4 class="page-header">
                    Collaborators
                </h4>
                <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label> Add New </label>
                    <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('task_name') ?: '' }}">
                    @if ($errors->has('task_name'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('task_name') }}</span>
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add User</button>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                </form>
</div>
```

my problem is this i need consider when I am in project 10 and I click collaborator link and then I need following localhost url

```
localhost:8000/project/10/collaborators
```

My existing routes is this

```
Route::get('/collaborators', function(){ 
       return view('collaborators.form'); 
    })->name('collaborators.form');
```

but it is generated only localhost url as

```
http://localhost:8000/collaborators
```

how can I manages this?

Comment: no any idea about this matter

Comment: hay  I need some help from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but are you trying to do this:

```
Route::get('/project/{project}/collaborators', function(){ 
       return view('collaborators.form'); 
    })->name('collaborators.form');
```

And use `route('collaborators.form', $project)`